# Bibtex style using [Jones1900] style citations?

Tags: bibtex

What is the simplest way to switch a LaTeX document, which makes use of `bibtex`, to citations including the full author name?

I'm currently using `amsalpha.bst` and the citation is `[Jon00]`. I'd prefer to get the full name `[Jones1900]`. However, I do not want `Jones et. al. (1900)` or similar.

I couldn't find appropriate bst files on google. The best approximation is [Jones00 style via makebst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127695/bibtex-style-like-jones90/127701#127701).

Comment: I'm not aware of any ready-made alpha-style bst files that implement your preferred citation style. I was going to suggest you look into running the `makebst` utility to create a custom bst file from scratch, but I then realized you're already familiar with (or at least aware of) that method. Incidentally, how important is for you to show all four digits of the year portion, i.e., to show `1990` rather than just `90`?

Comment: @Mico You are right. `makebst` is the easiest solution and two digit years are acceptable.

Comment: I'll make my comment into an answer.

Comment: Would this answer work for you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82571/24336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any ready-made alpha-style bst files that implement your preferred citation style.

I was going to suggest you look into running the `makebst` utility to create a custom `.bst` file from scratch, but I then saw that you're already familiar with this method.

Incidentally, how important is for you to show all four digits of the year portion, i.e., to show 1990 rather than just 90?